# Does Socket accept also port?

Tags: java, sockets

```
boolean canConnect = true;
try {
    SocketAddress addr; // initialization not shown
    Socket s = new Socket();
    s.connect(addr);
    s.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    canConnect = false;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have a global string variable:

```
string ipaddress = "10.0.0.3:8080";
```

How do i assign this ipaddress to the `SocketAddress` addr ?

Comment: Your title has nothing apparent to do with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most basic way:

```
Socket s = new Socket(host, port);
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for this.

Alternatively, use the connect with an [InetSocketAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#InetSocketAddress%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
 s.connect( new InetSocketAddress(host, port) );
```